# Correcting for multiple testing on non-independent sliding windows

Tags: statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, multiple-comparisons, bioinformatics, moving-window

### Question

Values taken from adjecent windows in a sliding windows are corrolated. If I calculate a p-value from each window, how can I correct for the fact I have tested many windows, given that the windows aren't independent?

### Details

I have data points (sequencing read start positions) that can take any one of a limited set of descrete values (genomic positions within a gene).

Number of data points taking a given value is clearly binomially distributed:

$$
X_i \sim B(n,1/L)
$$

where n is the number of data points in total (the number of reads) and L is the number of values each one can take (i.e. the length of the gene).  Thus the probability of getting $x$ or more reads starting at the same point is:

$$ P(X_i \geq x) = 1 - P(X_i \leq x-1) $$

and the probability that any position in the gene has that many reads or greater is $ P(X \geq x) \times L $.

Now consider the situation where we are intersted in the number of data points falling within a window of positions. The number of reads in a given window is clearly distributed thus:

$$ W_i \sim B(n,s/L) $$

where s is the size of the window. We can easily calculate the probability that any given window will have $x$ or more reads. But what is the probability of *any* window having $x$ or more reads. We can't simply multiply by the number of windows ($L-s)$ because the windows aren't independent, and this would rapidly lead to p-values of greater than one.

So my question is, how do I calculate the probability that any window of size $s$ will contain $x$ or more reads?

Comment: Read starts only once per observation, so $P_{n=1}(X_i=1|X_j=1, j\neq i)=0$, right?

Comment: Yes, a read can only start once.